# Can I apply conditional inputting on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In excel,I want to input unique text in every cell of a column.suppose I adding name of some people on that column,and I don't want to add one persons name twice by mistake.so I want that if I input a person's name which already been inputted on that column,then I will not be able to input it again.I think it's some kind of conditional inputting.

Comment: Are you looking for a macro or some type of data validation?

Comment: If my understanding is correct you want to restrict data entry so that a particular column can't have duplicates. If so you can use Data Validation:  http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal07.html#dupstable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with column A, you can select the column, go to the Data Tab, in Data Tools pick Data Validation, allow custom, formula `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)<=1`

Comment: If it solves your question, please click the green checkmark next to the answer to mark the question as solved. This will allow people looking for a similar answer to see that this question has one and also allow people looking to answer questions to know this one has been answered.